# How do I install the Elementary theme?

Tags: 11.04, themes, elementary-theme

Is there a way of installing elementary theme in natty?

Answer (score 4):

You can find it [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/elementary_pbr_unity?content=141135) along with the explanation I'm quoting here :

> 1. Backup and/or rename the original Ambiance theme.
> 2. If you want it to theme the GDM and when sudoed then extract
>      `Ambiance.tar.gz` into `/usr/share/themes`
>      (after you have done step 1). Then do
>      step 3.
> 3. Otherwise you can just copy the included `metacity-1` folder into
>      `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance` and choose
>      to merge and replace all. Then do step
>      4.
> 4. Then drag `Ambiance.tar.gz` to the Appearance Preferences theme tab and
>      deselect then reselect Ambiance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Check http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/elementary_por_unity?content=141135 and follow the instructions.

[image: Elementary theme in Unity]